# how to remove marker on mapbox project

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I want to remove all markers from my `mapbox` project. I didn't initialize marker on map via `javascript`. It's from my `mapbox project/api`. I just make marker on `mapbox.com/projects`. I just try these but it didn't work. here is the screenshot of my project:[image: screenshot]

```
featureLayer.clearLayers();
L.mapbox.markerLayer().clearLayers();
markerLayer.clearLayers();
```

How can I remove all markers from my map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've initialized your `L.mapbox.Map` with a project ID (Assuming, since you've shared completely no code in which we can see how you setup is) and thus the `L.mapbox.featureLayer` is being created for you, you can get a reference to your featureLayer from your map instance like this:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'your-project-id');

var featureLayer = map.featureLayer;
```

When you got a reference to your featureLayer you can use the `clearLayers` method:

```
featureLayer.clearLayers();
// or in short without declaring a separate var:
map.featureLayer.clearLayers();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i have no clue as to what you are saying. 'i think marker is not layer it's feature'?!?! Makes completely no sense. Since you've still not edited your question and shared the code you are using to initialize your map this is the best answer you're going to get. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to include the relevant information and code. Untill then, the best thing we can do is guess what you mean which will yield you no answers or bad ones. Good luck

Comment: Sorry i am bad for english, i can't explain very well. But it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this link for similar :
Go through this option https://www.mapbox.com/help/remove-feature-editor/